# What does the 'c' language represent in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Checking out my Google Analytics I see I am getting a good amount of hits from a language just called 'c'.

This normally wouldn't bug me, but all these 'c' hits have a 100% bounce rate. As these account for about 1/3 of my unique visits this has distorted my overall bounce rate overview.

Does anyone know what these 'c' visits are? Are these bots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost certainly bots.  There is a [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831839/in-google-analytics-what-does-the-locale-c-stands-for) that deals with this and the short answer is that it's a misconfigured environment variable.  Anything that registers that high of a bounce usually indicates a bot.  Or it indicates your site is really terrible (which I doubt).

Comment: Most of my technical websites have a 100% bounce rate. People search for one thing, read that one page, and leave. (Once in a while clicking on an ad.)

Comment: Makes sense to me...
How do we Remove the "c" (bots) from Google Tracking/Analysis (Affect on SEO) and Analytics of our site?